# Random pastel color for a brush

Tags: c++, qt

I have several `QPolygon` instances, which need to be filled with random colors (prefer pastels). Can I do this without creating an array of colors or using predefined colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pastel colours, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastel_%28color%29) have:

> high value and low to intermediate saturation.

So you can just use [`fromHsv`](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.6/qcolor/#fromhsv) method from `QColor` class, giving random number from range 0-359 for `h`, 0-128 (for example) for `s` and 192-255 (for example) for `v` parameter.

If you don't want two colours to be two similar to each other, you can quantize the ranges: draw random numbers from 0-35, 0-12 and 19-25 (also, rough example) and multiply by 10.